# Adding Retry mechanism to Watir in case of Timeout

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a series of scripts that I have developed using Ruby and the Watir gem. Those are wrapped by Spinach, but that is beside what I am about to ask.

The intent of those scripts is to do some functional spot check or simply alleviate some very repetitive tasks.

They have been running well for a while, but lately, I've started to see a lot of failure due to Timeouts between the Chromedriver / Geckodriver (tried both browsers) and the scripts. Of course, I could simply restart the script, but when the success rate goes below 70 % it really starts to be aggravating.

What I ended up doing is wrap up all of my calls to Watir in a Proc with a Begin, rescue that would do a retry in case of a timeout.

This is ugly and violates so many *rules* that I am nearly ashamed to had to resort to this solution, but at least using this my scripts are now completing.

here is how I worked around the issue:

```
# takes a proc and wraps it around a series of rescue
def execute_block_and_rety_if_needed
  yield
rescue Net::ReadTimeout
  puts 'Read Timeout detected, retrying operation'
  retry
rescue Net::HTTPRequestTimeOut
  puts 'Http Request Timeout detected, retrying operation'
  retry
rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT
  puts 'Errno::ETIMEDOUT detected, retrying operation'
  retry
end
```

a sample use would look like this:

```
execute_block_and_rety_if_needed { @browser.link(name: 'OK').wait_until_present.click } # click the 'OK' button
```

As you can see, this clearly violates the DRY principle as I need to call this proc every single time.

My question is: how can I move this as a module / feature of Watir so that it picks it up automatically. (ideally I would add a maximum number of retry to prevent an infinite loop).

Version information:
 - Chromedriver => 2.29.461585
 - GeckoDriver => 0.16.1
 - Firefox => ESR 52
 - Chrome => 58
 - Watir => 6.2.1

As far as the DRY comment, I referred to the fact that I had to wrap ALL of my Watir calls with the proc, sorry if this wasn't clear.

```
execute_block_and_rety_if_needed { @browser.link(name: 'User').wait_until_present.click } # click the 'Edit' button 
execute_block_and_rety_if_needed { @browser.link(name: 'Cancel').wait_until_present.click } # click the 'Cancel' button 
execute_block_and_rety_if_needed { @browser.link(name: 'OK').wait_until_present.click } # click the 'OK' button
```

The above is just an example that has to happen if I want to use the retry mechanism.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the versions of `chromedriver` and `geckodriver` along with the respective browser versions?  Are you running latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want to retry every command sent to the browser, you might want to consider addressing the issue in the underlying Selenium-WebDriver rather than Watir. Watir commands get sent to Selenium-WebDriver, which in turn sends them to the browser/driver.

Each command (or at least most) is currently sent through `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http:Default#request`. You could patch the method to wrap it in a retry. Not only would your clicks retry for timeouts, but so would every other command - eg navigation, setting fields, getting values, etc.

```
# Patch to retry timeouts during requests
require 'watir'
module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    module Remote
      module Http
        module DefaultExt
          def request(*args)
            tries ||= 3
            super
          rescue Net::ReadTimeout, Net::HTTPRequestTimeOut, Errno::ETIMEDOUT => ex
            puts "#{ex.class} detected, retrying operation"
            (tries -= 1).zero? ? raise : retry            
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.prepend(Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::DefaultExt)

# Then you can use Watir as usual
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome   # this will retry timeouts
browser.goto('http://www.example.com') # this will also retry timeouts
browser.link.click                     # this will also retry timeouts
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. This allowed me to remove all the wrapping I did with the blocks, code is in much better state now.

Thanks so much @Justin Ko !

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use a block for this. You can implement a method that does something like:

```
def ensure_click(element, retries = 3)
  @retries ||= retries
  element.click
rescue Net::ReadTimeout, Net::HTTPRequestTimeOut, Errno::ETIMEDOUT => ex
  raise unless @retries > 0
  @retries = @retries - 1
  puts "#{ex.class} detected, retrying"
  retry
end

...
ensure_click(@browser.link(name: 'User'))
...
```

That being said, those exceptions are not typically driver errors, but network issues of some sort. The are not normal.

Comment: This is indeed cleaner. I'll make sure to move toward that direction.

Sub-question tough: is there a way to make Watir do that everywhere without having to rewrite all my scripts?

As far as the network issue, there is, unfortunately, nothing I can do about it. This is outside of my sphere of influence and have to deal with it, hence the retry mechanism.

Comment: Hmm, maybe we could put the after hook calls inside a rescue block, and pass the exception as a parameter to that method. It would let you set a Proc to run after every potential DOM reset. But that would mean putting it in multiple places, which isn't very elegant either. It's on our list to implement the after hooks with Selenium Event listeners, maybe during that we can revisit. For now, doing the method replacement is best.

Comment: Sounds good. Want me to mark as resolved, or leave it open until you guys have done the revisit ?

Comment: Revisit may not happen, and if it does, there is no guarantee that it will address this issue. If this is sufficient to DRY your code to your satisfaction, please mark as resolved.